# How do I use the azure_table_service.query_entities result and token in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to us the Ruby Azure SDK to query an Azure Table.  I can get the call to work, and if I look at the wireshark it's returning tons of results.  But I can't figure out how to iterate through them.

```
query = {:filter => "Timestamp ge datetime'2015-01-01T00:00:00Z'", :select => ["FileName"]}
result, token = azure_table_service.query_entities("ActivityTable", query)
p result
p token
```

Shows this as the output.

```
#<Azure::Table::Entity:0xb8f74fdc @properties={"FileName"=>"LOCKINFO.DAT"}, @table="ActivityTable", @updated=2015-01-06 20:22:14 UTC, @etag=nil>
#<Azure::Table::Entity:0xb8f74f3c @properties={"FileName"=>"Scan000.pdf"}, @table="ActivityTable", @updated=2015-01-06 20:22:14 UTC, @etag=nil>
```

I tried result.count, result.pop, and others.  The documentation really sucks too, https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/azure/table/table_service.rb.  I looks like I'm getting an array of EnumerationResults back but none of the array calls work.

I also can't figure out how to use the token to get the next set of results but that's after I can figure out how to use the ones I have.

-Update-

```
p result.class
p token.class
```

Shows that both are Azure::Table::Entity

Answer (score 0):

Okay!  I found an issue with the documentation I guess.  I shouldn't use their example since

```
result = azure_table_service.query_entities("XASActivityTable", query)
```

returns an array of the expected values.  Adding that Token variable seems to cause some type of Ruby magic where the first and second values are put into the variables and the rest are dumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status by using below statement.

status = result.properties['status']